# Present UINavigationController from SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIViewController that I want presented from my SwiftUI view, the issue is that I need the UIViewController wrapped in a UINavigationController, how can I present that wrapped VC from my SwiftUI View?

This is what I've tried, it works for presenting the view controller but I do not know how to wrap it in a navigation controller:

```
struct ComposeTakeView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ComposeTakeVC {
        return ComposeTakeVC(nibName: "ComposeTakeVC", bundle: nil)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ComposeTakeVC, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

In the SwiftUI view:

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showComposeTake, content: {
                    ComposeTakeView()
                })
```

I've also tried creating a new SwiftUI view with NavigationView and tool bar, but this does not show the tool bar button:

```
struct ComposeTakeNavView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ComposeTakeView()
        }
        .toolbar {
            
            Button {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can wrap it right inside representable and return just as base class, like

```
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
    let controller = ComposeTakeVC(nibName: "ComposeTakeVC", bundle: nil)
    return UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
    
}
```